# Json.Net returns two errors when a value is incorrect format

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created a really simple web api that has an model class as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller message as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Person person)
{
}
```

When I call this with the following json request:

```
{
    "age": "a"
}
```

I get:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "Required property 'age' not found in JSON. Path '', line 3, position 1."
        ],
        "age": [
            "Could not convert string to integer: a. Path 'age', line 2, position 11."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "80000007-0003-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting two error values here especially as one is clearly untrue... Any ideas? I don't want to change to [Required] as you lose the nice error explaining which line number the error occured on.

Thanks

Comment: This is happening because 1) The server collects up all the errors and returns them to you after deserialization is complete, using Json.NET's [error handling mechanism](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm); 2) There are actually 2 errors here conceptually: i. `"a"` could not be deserialized to an int; ii. The required property `Age` was never set.  The error message is misleading however, if it said `"Required property 'age' not set from the JSON.` things would probably be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON value you're providing is not valid, the property Age is expecting a number, the JSON object should be similar to :

```
{
    "Age": 22
}
```

As for JSON, a property value can be a string (with simple or double quotes), a number (without quotes), true or false, null, an object or an array.

Comment: Hi, I know its not valid. My question is why does it return two errors?

"Required property 'age' not found in JSON. Path '', line 3, position 1."  isn't true as age is supplied (albeit its an invalid value.

Comment: Tried to reproduce the problem, the only error i get is related to the type of the property: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]. Path: $.age | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 14."

Comment: Hi acheddir. Is that via a web API?